# Is selenium webdriver browser not secure for logging into Google account?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, youtube, google-colaboratory

I installed selenium webdriver on google colab and tried to login youtube studio using my google account from https://accounts.google.com but after entering my email and pressing the next button, I encountered the following error!
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4DMF.png)
**How to fix this?

Is there another way to access YouTube Studio without logging into a Google account? Something similar to mount Google Drive to Google colab**

Comment: May you precise what YouTube data are you interested in? Otherwise this project may help you: https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver

Comment: @BenjaminLoison want to upload video to youtube using google colab and selenium.

Comment: Why not using [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Videos: insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) endpoint?